# Different appearance of identical layout. Why?

Tags: android, layout, settings

The following pictures show a preference screen for editing a game profile. 
The minimum number of players is 2 but the user can add more players by clicking on item "Add a new player..." (see picture 2).

[image: Picture 1]
[image]

All additional players can also be removed again by clicking on the trashcan-icon on the right side of the item. In order for the trashcan-icon to work correctly, I had to slightly modify the system provided layout for preference-items called `preference.xml`. The modified layout I use for dynamically added preference items looks like this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the only difference between this and the original system layout is the additional attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`,
all style specific definitions are the same.
How comes, that the added preference item looks different in style compared to the other ones? Look at the title, it is bigger and the icon's position is bit different.

I really don't understand why this behaves like this, do you have an explanation for this?

Here's the code, where I add a new preference to the category:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {

        final Context context = preference.getContext();
        final Preference newPref = new RemovablePreference(context);
        final PreferenceCategory playerCategory = (PreferenceCategory) preference
                .getPreferenceManager().findPreference("prof_key_players");

        final int count = playerCategory.getPreferenceCount();
        String title = String.valueOf(count) + ". Player";
        newPref.setTitle(title);
        final String summary = "Player" + String.valueOf(count);
        newPref.setIcon(R.drawable.player_green);
        newPref.setSummary(summary);
        newPref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference);
        newPref.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.view_profile_remove);
        newPref.setOrder(count);

        playerCategory.addPreference(newPref);

        title = "Players (" + String.valueOf(count) + ")";
        playerCategory.setTitle(title);

        Toast.makeText(context, "New player added ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How do you add the new player? If you're doing it via code and you're passing null for the parent, the style will be ignored. Add the code where you create and add the new row and we can probably figure this out fast.

Comment: Turn on the Show layout bounds option and post screenshot, maybe you'll figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: ok guys, thx, I will try your suggestions and give report to you. I'll be back in around 4 hours ...

Comment: I added the code, where I create and add the new row ... .